# can you do other tasks in python while using time.sleep()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a program that uses time.sleep()

I want to start the program and have an item continuously moving(this part I have sorted).

I then want the program to 'sleep' for a specified time period (either 1, 2, 5, 10 minutes)

During this 'sleep' time, if someone pushes a button connected to the equipment, then everything stops moving.

If they push the button after the specified time, then everything works well.

Is it possible to have this happen with time.sleep() or is there an alternative, better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `time.sleep()`, and you don't need a tight loop (or any sort of loop) to check against the clock. All you need to do is set a flag at the start, then use the `after` message to clear the flag after the desired time. Then, you button function merely needs to check the flag to see if it's OK to do whatever it needs to do.

For example:

```
...
b = tk.Button(..., command=self.pause)
def pause(self):
    if self.is_sleeping:
        self.pause()
...
self.is_sleeping = True
self.after(sleep_period, lambda: self.is_sleeping = False)
self.start_animation()
```

Comment: This might seem a silly question but: Can I just write self.after(sleep_period, lambda: self.is_sleeping = False) and change lambda: to be self.pause()? So it would be self.after(sleep_period, self.pause(), self.is_sleeping = False) From what I understand lambda is a place holder for a function that doesn't actually exist. Is this right? I have read the docs on after() but there are no good code examples.

Comment: @pythonReuser: I don't quite understand what you are asking. You can replace the lambda with any function you want. You can do `self.after(sleep_period, self.pause)`, if you want `self.pause` to be called after the sleep period.

Comment: I think I was just confusing myself by overcomplicating it. self.after(sleep_period, self.pause) is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sleep` - it is useless.

You can use clock and check if it is time to do some things - it is not ideal.

Not ideal pseudo code:

```
time_to_wake_up = current_time + 10 minutes
pause = False # move objects

while True:

     if time_to_wake_up > current_time:

           if button_was_press:
                 if not pause:
                       pause = True
                       time_to_next_button_press = current_time + 2 minutes
                 else current_time > time_to_next_button_press:
                       pause = False

     check_events_and_run_other_stuff

     if not pause:
            change_objects_position
            draw_everything
```

You have main loop to do all stuff and you decide what should be done at current moment.

It is not ideal - maybe there are better solution.

Comment: time.sleep() is not useless - it's important when you're busy in a tight loop, spinning on the CPU.  Granted, you may want to time.sleep(0.01) inside an otherwise-tight loop, but even just that helps load a system quite a bit less.

Comment: @dstromberg: time.sleep() is totally useless in a GUI. It freezes the ui, preventing events from being processed and leading to a poor user experience.

Comment: Unless you're using concurrency.

Comment: @furas, I would upvote your answer, but I only have 6 rep atm. Your description helped quite a bit, but Bryan Oakley's answer was easier to write and add to my existing code.

Comment: @pythonReuser Bryan Oakley's answer is definitly better. My answer is only pseudocode and probably it is more suitable to other GUI or PyGame.